# How do I define the lifetime for a tokio task spawned from a class?

Tags: rust, lifetime

I'm attempting to write a generic `set_interval` function helper:

```rust
pub fn set_interval<F, Fut>(mut f: F, dur: Duration)
where
    F: Send + 'static + FnMut() -> Fut,
    Fut: Future<Output = ()> + Send + 'static,
{
    let mut interval = tokio::time::interval(dur);

    tokio::spawn(async move {
        // first tick is at 0ms
        interval.tick().await;
        loop {
            interval.tick().await;
            tokio::spawn(f());
        }
    });
}
```

This works fine until it's called from inside a class:

```rust
fn main() {}

struct Foo {}

impl Foo {
    fn bar(&self) {
        set_interval(|| self.task(), Duration::from_millis(1000));
    }
    
    async fn task(&self) {
        
    }
}
```

`self` is not `'static`, and we can't restrict lifetime parameter to something that is less than `'static` because of `tokio::task`.

Is it possible to modify `set_interval` implementation so it works in cases like this?

---

[Link to playground](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=0042bf10b3d8de9a4ca3906c75aee47d)

---

P.S. Tried to

```rust
let instance = self.clone();
set_interval(move || instance.task(), Duration::from_millis(1000));
```

but I also get an error: error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body

Answer (score 3):

> Is it possible to modify set_interval implementation so it works in cases like this?

Not really. Though `spawn`-ing `f()` really doesn't help either, as it precludes a simple "callback owns the object" solution (as you need either both callback and future to own the object, or just future).

I think that leaves two solutions:

1. Convert everything to shared mutability `Arc`, the callback owns one `Arc`, then on each tick it clones that and moves the clone into the future (the `task` method).
2. Have the future (`task`) acquire the object from some external source instead of being called on one, this way the intermediate callback doesn't need to do anything. Or the callback can do the acquiring and move that into the future, same diff.

Incidentally at this point it could make sense to just create the future directly, but allow cloning it. So instead of taking a callback `set_interval` would take a clonable future, and it would `spawn()` clones of its stored future instead of creating them anew.

Comment: could you show how the implementations for those would work in the minimal repro in the playground?

Comment: @doplumi [this](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2021&gist=37b0f441f0b667fd3cd585b4b828e27f) would be the basic arcified version. Sadly for my second suggestion I'd forgotten that `async fn` don't auto-impl Clone ([see this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/69635431/8182118)), so this would require a lot more work as it would need handrolling the `task` future, or something along those lines.

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned by @Masklinn, you can **clone the Arc** to allow for this. Note that cloning the Arc will *not* clone the underlying data, just the pointer, so it is generally OK to do so, and should not have a major impact on performance.

Here is an example. The following code will produce the error `async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows data, which is owned by the current function`:

```rust
fn main() {
    //  Error: async block may outlive the current function, but it borrows data, which is owned by the current function
    let data = Arc::new("Hello, World".to_string());
    tokio::task::spawn(async {
        println!("1: {}", data.len());
    });
    tokio::task::spawn(async {
        println!("2: {}", data.len());
    });
}
```

Rust unhelpfully suggests adding `move` to both async blocks, but that will result in a borrowing error because there would be multiple ownership.

**To fix the problem**, we can clone the Arc for each task and *then* add the `move` keyword to the async blocks:

```rust
fn main() {
    let data = Arc::new("Hello, World".to_string());

    let data_for_task_1 = data.clone();
    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        println!("1: {}", data_for_task_1.len());
    });
    
    let data_for_task_2 = data.clone();
    tokio::task::spawn(async move {
        println!("2: {}", data_for_task_2.len());
    });
}
```